# Is it possible to increment a NSNumber variable in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumber

I used core data in my iOS swift project and declared a variable as `Int32`, in the class file it was initialised to `NSNumber` and while I tried to increment the variable by creating a object for that class, it shows that Binary operator += cannot be applied on `NSNumber`'s. Is it possible to increment the `NSNumber` or should I choose `Int16` or `Int64` to access the variable.

Comment: `NSNumber` objects are immutable. You need to create a new instance with a new value based on the original value.

Comment: Bold move by the person who down voted all of the answers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Here's three different answers from succinct to verbose:**

Given that NSNumbers are immutable, simply assign it a new value equal to what you want:

```
var num : NSNumber = NSNumber(integer: 1) // NSNumber of 1
num = num.integerValue + 1 // NSNumber of 2
```

Or you can assign it another way:

```
var num : NSNumber = NSNumber(integer: 1) // NSNumber of 1
num = NSNumber(integer: num.integerValue + 1) // NSNumber of 2
```

Or you can convert the `NSNumber` to an `Int`, increment the int, and reassign the `NSNumber`:

```
var num : NSNumber = NSNumber(integer: 1) // NSNumber of 1
var int : Int = Int(num)
int += 1
num = NSNumber(integer: int) // NSNumber of 2
```

Comment: All three answers worked correctly.. Thanks a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
var number = NSNumber(integer: 10)
number = number.integerValue + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use var. Because let means constants.

```
var mybalance = bankbalance as NSNumber
```

But NSNumber is a Object and mybalance.integerValue cannot be assigned.

```
if let bankbalance: AnyObject? = keystore.objectForKey("coinbalance"){
    let mybalance: NSNumber = bankbalance as NSNumber
    var b = mybalance.integerValue + 50;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to increment an NSNumber once the object is created. There is no [API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/) that allows that.

You have to recreate the NSNumber object with a new (incremented) value:

```
let number = NSNumber(int: 15)
let incrementedNumber = NSNumber(int: number.intValue + 1)
```